# Using mathematics in jquery to hide/show backgrounds with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

Good evening, I am tired and have been fighting with this for hours. I am using a sample I found and altering it for my needs. It uses jquery.bgpos.js to create a sliding background that changes behind another layer (the navigation) when the mouse is passed over it. It uses positioning and some inline styles in the page and I cannot get things to match up right.

My example is shown [here](http://statewideemergency.com/beta2/). When you hover over the text tabs, the background changes but do not position themselves correctly because, well, I have screwed it up. I hate to post all this code here but I am running out of time and only seek someone with a better understanding to correct my errors. Thanks.

Here's the html for the menu with background:

```
<div id="menuWrapper" class="menuWrapper bg1">
                <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                    <li class="bg1" style="background-position:0 0;">
                        <a id="bg1" href="#">Home</a>
                        <ul class="sub1" style="background-position:0 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Story</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Discography</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-163px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg2" href="#">News</a>
                        <ul class="sub2" style="background-position:-163px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-299px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg3" href="#">The Band </a>
                        <ul class="sub3" style="background-position:-163px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-449px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg4" href="#">Shows </a>
                        <ul class="sub4" style="background-position:-163px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                    <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-599px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg5" href="#">The Music</a>
                        <ul class="sub5" style="background-position:-163px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last bg1" style="background-position:-754px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg6" href="#">Videos</a>
                        <ul class="sub6" style="background-position:-163px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And here's the css:

```
/* MENU */
.menuWrapper{
    font-family: "Bebas Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.45em;
    height:485px;
    width:980px;
    background-position:0 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
ul.menu{
    list-style:none;
    width:980px;
}
ul.menu > li{
    float:left;
    width:163px;
    height:542px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:transparent;
}
ul.menu > li.last{
    border:none;
}
.bg1{
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
}
.bg2{
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
}
.bg3{
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
}
.bg4{
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
}
.bg5{
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
}
.bg6{
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
}
ul.menu > li > a{
    float:left;
    width:163px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1.5em;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#000;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 2.25em;
}
ul.menu > li ul{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
}
ul.menu > li ul li{
    display:none;
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub1{
    background-image:url(../images/bg1sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub2{
    background-image:url(../images/bg2sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub3{
    background-image:url(../images/bg3sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub4{
    background-image:url(../images/bg1sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub5{
    background-image:url(../images/bg2sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub6{
    background-image:url(../images/bg3sub.png); 
}
ul.menu > li ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:1.25em;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:1.5em;
    width: 163px;
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub1 li{
    display:block;
}
ul.menu > li ul li a:hover{

}
```

Finally, here's the js within my page (the part that's kicking my but)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    /* position of the <li> that is currently shown */
    var current = 0;

    var loaded  = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <4; ++i)
    $('<img />').load(function(){
    ++loaded;
    if(loaded == 3){
    $('#bg1,#bg2,#bg3,#bg4,#bg5,#bg6').mouseover(function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    /* if we hover the current one, then don't do anything */
    if($this.parent().index() == current)
    return;

    /* item is bg1 or bg2 or bg3, depending where we are hovering */
    var item = e.target.id;

    /*
    this is the sub menu overlay. Let's hide the current one if we hover the first <li> or if we come from the last one, then the overlay should move left -> right, otherwise right->left
    */
    if(item == 'bg1' || current == 5)
    $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-489px 0)"},300,function(){
    $(this).find('li').hide();
    });
    else
    $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(163px 0)"},300,function(){
    $(this).find('li').hide();
    });

    if(item == 'bg1' || current == 5){
    /* if we hover the first <li> or if we come from the last one, then the images should move left -> right */
    $('#menu > li').animate({backgroundPosition:"(-1000px 0)"},0).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg6').addClass(item);
    move(1,item);
    }
    else{
    /* if we hover the first <li> or if we come from the last one, then the images should move right -> left */
    $('#menu > li').animate({backgroundPosition:"(1000px 0)"},0).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg6').addClass(item);
    move(0,item);
    }

    /*
    We want that if we go from the first one to the last one (without hovering the middle one), or from the last one to the first one, the middle menu's overlay should also slide, either from left to right or right to left.
    */
    if(current == 5 && item == 'bg1'){
    $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-163px 0)"},300);
    }
    if(current == 0 && item == 'bg6'){
    $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+5)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(163px 0)"},300);
    }


    /* change the current element */
    current = $this.parent().index();

    /* let's make the overlay of the current one appear */

    $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},300,function(){
    $(this).find('li').fadeIn();
    });
    });
    }   
    }).attr('src', 'images/'+i+'.jpg');

    /*
    dir:1 - move left->right
    dir:0 - move right->left
    */
    function move(dir,item){
    if(dir){
    $('#bg1').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},200);
    $('#bg2').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-163px 0)"},300);
    $('#bg3').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-326px 0)"},400);
    $('#bg4').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-489px 0)"},500);
    ('#bg5').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-652px 0)"},600);
    $('#bg6').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-815px 0)"},700,function(){
    $('#menuWrapper').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg6').addClass(item);
    });
    }
    else{
    $('#bg1').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},700,function(){
    $('#menuWrapper').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg6').addClass(item);
    });
    $('#bg2').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-163px 0)"},600);
    $('#bg3').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-326px 0)"},500);
    $('#bg4').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-489px 0)"},400);
    $('#bg5').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-652px 0)"},300);
    $('#bg6').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-815px 0)"},200);
    }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Looking at that demo it seems fine to me in terms of the background. As I mouseover each menu item a bunch of images slide in from the side and arrange themselves to form one big seemless image. So either it works in some browsers (I tested in firefox) or I am missing the point. Only problem I can see is that the menus at the top start overlapping on THE BAND and THE MUSIC since they are split across two lines.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The trouble I'm having is the positioning of the colored box sub menus not hiding after you mouse out. It has something to do with the positioning in the pages javascript I think... maybe even the css. It ALMOST totally works as it should. The overlapping you are talking about I suppose is just the font not rendering correctly if I understand you right.

Comment: The off-positioning of those sub menus mainly looks wrong on the initial loading of the page. As you start to hover over the tabs, they seem to work as intended once you have hovered over them all.

Comment: yup, the menu overlap will be due to fonts. I suspect few people will have the "Bebas Neue" font since it isn't standard. Make sure you test it with the next font available (arial) so you can make sure it works for users without your font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a little unsure of what your problems is. when I initially look at the page the backgrounds are screwed up but after I start mousing over things then it actually makes them line up.

The reason that they don't look right initially is probably related to the fact that the UL.subN initial background position is `-163px 0`. However, when you are changing it programatically for "mouseout" you are setting it to -489px. I suspect if you started with them all at -489px then it would work.

I hope this is helpful but if not maybe some a screenshot of the bit of page that looks wrong to you.

Comment: my example is at statewideemergency.com/beta2. I'll work on the font issue, but it seems to work in Firefox for both Mac and PC for me. Haven't tried it yet in IE, Chrome, Safari or Opera.

Comment: @godleuf: Yeah, I looked at the example page you gave. Its just that in one place you seem to be saying that its when you mouseover that it screws up and when I mouse over it makes things better... And if the font is installed on the computer it will work, no matter the browser. If you find a computer without the font on you'll hopefully see the issue. Does the positioning I mentioned in my answer fix your problem at all?

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Staying up late and crunching numbers do not mix... there were the errors you pointed out above as well as other simple math errors that affected the positioning that I now realize after a few hours of sleep :) Thanks for stickin' with me man! I must have screwed up my css and didn't write the @font in correctly. I'll work on that but I am happy as hell on the nav/slider background :)